# $\int t^{m}(1-t^2)^n\sqrt{1- t^2} dt$ Vs. $\int \sin^{10} (x) \ dx$ which one is better

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I've an integral,
$$\int \sin^{10} (x)\cos^{10}(x) \ dx$$

Making it ready for the substitution $\sin(x) = t$,

$${ = \int \sin^{10} (x) (1-\sin^{2}(x))^4\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)} \cos(x)\ dx}$$

$$ = \int t^{10}(1-t^2)^4\sqrt{1- t^2}\ dt\tag{1}$$

Integration by parts might work here, but I think, there might be more precise way to solve it.

Also, the original integral can be simplified by applying identities as follows,
$$\int \sin^{10} (x) \cos^{10}(x) \ dx$$
$$ = \dfrac{1}{2^{10}}  \int \sin^{10} (2x) \ dx\tag{2}$$

I can't see anything good with this integral either.

---

My question is that, which one is easier to evaluate $(1)$ or $(2)$? Is any there other method to evaluate this integral?

## **Edit:**

I got the answer $\frac{-1}{2^{20}} \left[ \frac{\sin(20x)}{10} - \frac{5\sin(16x)}{4} + \dfrac{15\sin(12x)}{2} - 30 \sin(8x) + 105\sin(4x) - 252x\right] + C$ with egreg's method.

Comment: It looks like you replace $\cos^8x$ at one point with $1-\sin^8x$ instead of $(1-\sin^2x)^4$.

Comment: Aah yes, my bad. Thanks for pointing out. @J.G. I'll fix it soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Computing
$$
\int t^{n}\textstyle\sqrt{1-t^2}\,dt
$$
is essentially the same as computing integrals of the form
$$
\int \sin^m x\,dx
$$
because in the former you can do $t=\sin x$ and get
$$
\int (\sin^nx-\sin^{n+2}x)\,dx
$$
It's *much* easier to do the latter, in your case
$$
\frac{1}{2^{10}}\int\sin^{10}(2x)\,dx=\frac{1}{2^{11}}\int \sin^{10}u\,du
$$
You can use a reduction formula using integration by parts, but it's easier if you use Euler's formulas:
$$
\sin u=\frac{e^{iu}-e^{-iu}}{2i}
$$
Expanding with the binomial theorem will give you an expression in terms of the cosine of multiples of $u$ and the antiderivative is readily computed from it.

Let me do it for the case $4$:
$$
\sin^4u
=\frac{1}{2^4}(e^{4iu}-4e^{2iu}+6-4e^{-2iu}+e^{-4iu})=\frac{1}{2^3}(\cos4u-4\cos2u+6)
$$

Comment: Now I'm wondering what if the power is 100 instead of just 10 i.e. $\int \sin^{100}(x) \ dx$ LOL

Comment: @Utkarsh Just lookup the relevant row in the arithmetic triangle… :-)

Comment: Haha.. BTW thanks for the answer ^_^

Comment: After applying brute force binomial theorem, I got $$\frac{-1}{2^{20}} \left[ \frac{\sin(20x)}{10} - \frac{5\sin(16x)}{4} + \dfrac{15\sin(12x)}{2} - 30 \sin(8x) + 105\sin(4x) - 252x\right] + C$$

Comment: @Utkarsh Looks right